# Probability Distribution of batch in keras

Tags: keras, batch-processing, probability-distribution

I am trying to train a CNN model on imbalanced dataset. I wanted to know how well a batch approximates the distribution in the training dataset. Is there any parameter in an inbuilt function in keras which could be specified to maintain the same distribution in batches?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to train and get good results depending on how severe the imbalance is.

But yes, there are easy ways to compensate this, such as using `sample_weight` and `class_weight` in the `fit` method.

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) on the `fit` method:

> - class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.
> - sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify `sample_weight_mode="temporal"` in `compile()`.

So, you can compensate three kinds of imbalance:

- Class imbalance: when you have classes (results) that are more present than others
- Sample imbalance: when some of the inputs are more important than others
- Temporal (or 2D) imbalance: when some steps in a sequence are more important than others

Comment: Thanks for the respose. You solution will work for a classification model. I am trying to train a regression model on data which has data points clustered around the centre. The distribution is almost gaussian. I wanted to know if same distribution will be maintained in the batches as well.

Comment: Actually, `sample_weight` is totally independent of the kind of model you're using. It's sample-wise (acts based on the input's, not the outputs). --- But I don't understand you question... what is distributed? The inputs or the outputs? A neural network is deterministic. For the same input, it will always predict the same output.

Comment: The output labels are distributed. Input is 512x512 image and output is normalized user rating on an image (in the range of 0 to 1)

Comment: So, you expect the same image to generate different results??

Comment: You should probably work with a distrubution formula, such as normal, and make the network output the distribution's parameters instead.